Access Hard Drive by Nickname
What I would like to do is access an internal hard drive by it’s ‘nickname’ (label?) – easier for command line and scripts.  Right now the HDD’s icon is labeled “WD_4TB”, which is what I would like to use instead of the UUID.  I’ve seen how to create the label but have been unable to find how to make it usable with Terminal.  (/dev/sdb2  can be highly variable so learned not to use that!)
The line from fstab is:
'''/dev/disk/by-uuid/75d4f7d7-2cde-4f32-87be-5145a31428de /mnt/75d4f7d7-2cde-4f32-87be-5145a31428de auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=WD_4TB 0 0'''
Right now lsblk -o  (lsblk -o | grep -i WD_4TB) isn’t retrieving the label so appears I’m missing a step or two.  Or I’m using the wrong terminology.
I’m using Ubuntu 24.04.
Thanks!


Or I’m using the wrong terminology.

Yes. And the more logical approach would be a "mountpoint".
Create a personal mountpoint (we nowadays use the root for this but in the older days /mnt was used for internal disks so you can use that too): I have a /discworld/ that I use and I have all my normal directories (ie. Desktop, Downloads) there set to a group so wifey, kids can use its content (stream  movies, music).
Replace /mnt/75d4f7d7-2cde-4f32-87be-5145a31428de  by /discword and create the directory (set to your owner and you as a group and permissions 700. Depending on usage you can set the group to a shared one and use 750 or 770 for permissions.

A label is used when a partition is not in fstab, but mounted by the gui using udev. Default is UUID, but if label then that is used. You need to create a mount point, give yourself ownershiip & permissions & mount using that mount point. Note that mountpoint & label are not same. I used Data for one & data for the other and got very confused. An example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Thanks to Rinzwind and oldfred -- I have done a similar process on older/other computers, just the lengthy UUID confused me.  Working as desired now!
